# Trying to send FCM push to Android and iOS

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Trying to send FCM pushes to both Android and iOS. Android sent fine but wouldn't send to iOS. Added a new function that sends to iOS. Now I get responseserializationfailed on iOS and `{"multicast_id":8264919538226996033,"success":1,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"message_id":"0:1523928629201044%3990eb5d3990eb5d"}]}`

on android for any calls that include the apple push. I also occasionally, but not often, get two pushes to android, but never two to apple. This is an example call and that Apple line is what causes errors, even though it sends everything.

```
$json = $push->getPush();
$firebase->sendMultiple($tokens, $json);
$firebase->sendPushNotificationApple($tokens, $payload["title"], $payload["message"], $payload);
```

The push functions in another file

```
public function getPush() {
            $res = array();
            $res['title']       = $this->title;
            $res['message']     = $this->message;
            $res['image']       = $this->image;
            $res['payload']     = $this->data;
            $res['type']        = $this->type;
            $res['timestamp']   = date("T-m-d G:i:s");
            $res['text']        = $this->message;
            $res['sound']       = "default";
            $res['badge']       = "1";
            return $res;
        }
// sending push message to multiple users by firebase registration ids
    public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
            'priority'=>'high',
        );

    return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
}

// function makes curl request to firebase servers
public function sendPushNotification($fields) {

    define("FIREBASE_API_KEY", "removed");

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . FIREBASE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}

public function sendPushNotificationApple($registration_ids, $title, $text, $payload) {

    $url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    $serverKey = 'removed';
    $notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $text, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1', 'payload' => $payload);
    $arrayToSend = array('registration_ids' => $registration_ids, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
    $json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
    //Send the request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //Close request
    if ($response === FALSE) {
    die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Did you receive the test push notification on iOS from GoogleFCM dashboard?

Comment: Yes, and I receive the iOS notification from this script as well, it just returns a failure in my JSON response. Removing the Apple push and only leaving the Android one does not return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the sendNotificationPushApple line, did not change the sendPushNotification function, and changed the sendMultiple function to this and it solved the problem:

```
public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
            'notification' => $message,
            'priority'=>'high',
        );

        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }
```